# How to remove default bottom devider from DataTable widget in flutter

Tags: flutter, dart

[image]

How to remove default bottom devider from DataTable() widget

here is my code

```
return SingleChildScrollView(
  scrollDirection: Axis.vertical,
  child: SingleChildScrollView(
    scrollDirection: Axis.horizontal,
    child: DataTable(
      dividerThickness: 0,
        decoration: BoxDecoration(
            border: Border.all(
          width: 1,
          color: Color(0xFFE6E7EB),
        )),
        columns: [
          DataColumn(label: Text('RollNo')),
          DataColumn(label: Text('Name')),
        ],
        rows: [
          DataRow(cells: [
            DataCell(Text('1')),
            DataCell(Text('Arya')),
          ]),
          DataRow(cells: [
            DataCell(Text('1')),
            DataCell(Text('Arya')),
          ])
        ]),
  ),
);
```

I tried to set devider thickness value to 0 but it still shows some border bellow it

Answer (score 13, accepted):

wrap your DataTable with the Theme widget and change the divide color to transparent also set dividerThickness to 0 in DataTable like this :

```
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Theme(
      data: Theme.of(context).copyWith(dividerColor: Colors.transparent),
       child:DataTable(
       dividerThickness:0.0,
      columns: const <DataColumn>[
        DataColumn(
          label: Text(
            'Name',
            style: TextStyle(fontStyle: FontStyle.italic),
          ),
        ),
        DataColumn(
          label: Text(
            'Age',
            style: TextStyle(fontStyle: FontStyle.italic),
          ),
        ),
        DataColumn(
          label: Text(
            'Role',
            style: TextStyle(fontStyle: FontStyle.italic),
          ),
        ),
      ],
      rows: const <DataRow>[
        DataRow(
          cells: <DataCell>[
            DataCell(Text('Sarah')),
            DataCell(Text('19')),
            DataCell(Text('Student')),
          ],
        ),
        DataRow(
          cells: <DataCell>[
            DataCell(Text('Janine')),
            DataCell(Text('43')),
            DataCell(Text('Professor')),
          ],
        ),
        DataRow(
          cells: <DataCell>[
            DataCell(Text('William')),
            DataCell(Text('27')),
            DataCell(Text('Associate Professor')),
          ],
        ),
      ],
    ));
  }
```

Comment: I tried this solution on my side by seems like it is not working at all, the divider still can be seen in the data table....

Comment: Hey @Leong, I added a new solution below.

Answer (score 4):

There is a new DividerTheme object for the Material 3. Here is how you can make the dividers disappear.

```
Container(
      child: Theme(
        data: Theme.of(context).copyWith(
          dividerColor: Colors.transparent,
          dividerTheme: const DividerThemeData(
            color: Colors.transparent,
            space: 0,
            thickness: 0,
            indent: 0,
            endIndent: 0,
          ),
        ), // set divider color to transparent
        child: Container( // .... some data table below
```

Answer (score 2):

The easiest way to disable the divider is to set the dividerThickness like this:

```
DataTable(
  dividerThickness: 0.00000000001,
)
```

You CAN'T set the value to zero!!!